# Understanding TooManyLogicalSession error

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

We have a mongodb cluster setup of 14 nodes consisting of 2 replica set(3 data nodes + 1 arbiter node),  3 routers nodes and 3 configuration nodes. We are using mongodb community version `4.0.5`.

Nodes are configured with:

- Data nodes: 8 GB ram and 4 core cpu.
- Configuration nodes: 8 GB ram and 4 core cpu.
- Router nodes: 8 GB ram and 4 core cpu.

Recently after increasing the input load we started seeing a couple of data node crashing as they were not able to handle the given load.
So, we ended up in increasing the amount of RAM to 16 GB(*depending upon the load on **data node***) which let it work for a while. But after sometime the loading application again started crashing.

We searched a bit more and saw an error in `mongod.log`
which stated :  `cannot add session into the cache" errName:TooManyLogicalSessions`.

We than verified that by running the `db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1, repl: 1, metrics: 0, locks: 0 } )` which resulted as:

```
"logicalSessionRecordCache" : {
    "activeSessionsCount" : 1000223,
```

So, with this we got to know that our logical session's are chocking up which has a default limit of `1000000`(*if not set*).  So, we increased the
[maxSessions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.maxSessions) count to twice of default(*because of the load*) in the config as:

```
setParameter:
    maxSessions: 2000000
```

But even after increasing the session count (*and restarting the nodes*) we are seeing the same error message again and when re-check the `serverStatus`. We were able to see that the activeSessionCount was able to passed the previous limit and but still the queries are crashing.

We even verified the setting with by running command:

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, "maxSessions": 1 } )
```

Which gave us the correct count, but looks like some how the nodes/mongodb instances are not considering it. even when the logic in mongodb is also verifying the same:

[link to mongodb file checking the field](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/b07f80de5850c665e75dc259def6b8999d1077dd/src/mongo/db/logical_session_cache_impl.cpp#L455)
[image]

Can anyone help me in understanding it how can one resolve such an issue.

Comment: Assuming you do not really need 1m concurrent sessions, either your application or your driver is leaking sessions. You also don't need an arbiter in that setup.

Comment: @D.SM yes from application side there is a leakage but the problem is not with them. As before increasing the load db was able to accommodate everything in the same session range. That's the reason why we updated the `maxSession`  but mongodb is in't considering it.

Comment: If you set maxsession to 2m, and you are receiving the error at 1m sessions, create a reproduce case and file a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/SERVER/issues.